# pouch server on shared webspace

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pouchdb

I use PouchDB for a web application. For the synchronization, I installed the PouchDB server locally for testing.
Unfortunately I don't have my own server in the www, but only a shared webspace (with apache, SSH connection & limited bash commands).
I can install and start the pouch server on this, but I cannot get a connection from outside because the web server only listens on port 80, but the pouch server runs on port 5984.

The pouch server should be accessible at: `sub.domain.tdl/pouchserver`

For this purpose, I have created a `.htacces` file in this directory with the following content:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:5984/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:5984/$1 [P,L]
```

Calling: `sub.domain.tdl:5984/pouchserver/_utils` results in an error page: `Connection Failed`

My question is, can I redirect the request via `.htaccess` so that it is sent to the pouch server?
If yes how?

Link: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server#usage

edit2:
I found my first mistake. Of course, I am not allowed to call port 5984, or I am not surprised that there is no answer from there.
What I would like is that the request from the browser on port 80 of the `.htaccess` is redirected to port 5984.
But a call to: `sub.domain.tdl/pouchserver/_utils` only results in: `The requested URL was not found on this server.`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "Calling: sub.domain.tdl:5984/pouchserver/_utils only results in an error page." mean? 1. _what_ error do you get and 2. this obviously won't work as you have explained yourself, since that port is not open.

Comment: Another things... You tagged this question "node.js", yet you are trying to use rules that comply with the apache http server's rewriting module. While that _is_ possible it is a very unusual approach. Are you sure that describes your actual setup?

Comment: thx @arkascha, i did some edits on my post, hopefully it helps.

Comment: You added the error message, thanks. Apart from that I cannot really make more sense of the question. Still the URL you apparently test has a port number pointing to a port you yourself said is not reachable. So why are you surprised that this does not work?

Comment: @arkascha, thank you and see my second edit.

Comment: Ah, OK, now that is indeed a step forward. That requested URL does make sense and the rules _should_ work. So the question is what is wrong here. Could be several things. Apparently the rule does not get applied, so there are two potentional issues here: either you have other rules implemented (in the same file or in the central configuration) which interfere (get applied _before_ that rule here comes into play or the proxy and the proxy_http modules you rely on are not actually loaded into the http server. So please check that http server's error log file for more details as a first step.